# MCP16301 Step Down Voltage Regulator PCB Layout Validation

Tags: voltage-regulator, pcb-design, buck, layout, switching-regulator

I'm looking for some feedback/validation that the layout for this MCP16301 is correct. I'm trying to get 600mA 3.3v Out from 12 input.

I'm using the circuit as described in the [datasheet on page 23](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/20005004D.pdf) and *loosly* based on the layout on page 21.

Here's my current PCB layout:

- Cin - C2/C3 : 4.7uf
- Rtop - R8: 31.6k
- Rbot - R9: 10k
- L1: 15uH
- Cb - C6: 100nF
- FW Diode - D4: Diode Schottky 40v
- Boost Diode - D5: 1N4148
- Cout - C7/C8: 10uF
- Reg1: MCP16301

The smaller traces are 10mil and the larger ones are 25mil. 
[image]

REVISED PER COMMENTS(location moved and orientation flipped, but same circuit:
[image: Revised Circuit]

Revised to larger package D4 SOD123 40v 1A [Diodes](http://www.digikey.com/product-search/en/discrete-semiconductor-products/diodes-rectifiers-single/1376383?k=&pkeyword=&pv143=235&FV=400151%2C401610%2C402650%2C40277d%2C4034bf%2C403ccf%2C1800018%2Ce500017%2Cfff40015%2Cfff8007f%2Ce48000e%2Ce480012%2Ce480013%2Ce4800bc%2Ce4800bf&mnonly=0&newproducts=0&ColumnSort=0&page=1&stock=1&quantity=0&ptm=0&fid=0&pageSize=500):
[image]

Is component placement and routing correct? Anything that I should change? Is the large 3.3Vout pad going to create soldering issues?

Comment: I would fatten your current-carrying traces up or switch to polygon fills. Also, there's probably no need for thermals, eliminate those to improve your pad connectivity.

Comment: The data sheet suggests a schottky in a SMA package; this is quite a bit chunkier than the device you have at the moment which appears to have the same dimensions as the boost diode (SOD323 if you use the recommended device).

Comment: Continuing from my comment above, the schottky needs to be sized according to average current; what is your *minimum* Vin?

Comment: Path from Vout to Boost pin (current through boost diode) needs bigger copper area (thicker track).

Comment: @PeterSmith average vin is 13.5V

Answer (score 1):

trace from ground and pin2 need to be more thicker, internal gate current requires a good return pad. Also make sure D4 can drive at least twice load current. if you can improve the thermal dissipation of reg1 adding more cooper under it or bottom layer

Comment: See the revise circuit. I have also found a 1.5a diode for D4. Would this suffice? [SOD323 1.5A Diode](http://www.digikey.com/product-detail/en/toshiba-semiconductor-and-storage/CUS15S40,H3F/CUS15S40H3FCT-ND/5114380)

Comment: I think  board look better but the diode is a little tiny i could not find the Rth(j-a) on the datasheet but  I find similar package and is about 415C/W.  the  forward voltage of  diode is about 0.25V at 600mA, so in the worst case you need to dissipate 150mW then  the temperature rise of D4 will be 415C/W*0.15= 62C + Tambient  good design consider ambient temperature of 60C so I recommend a bigger diode package

Comment: Do you think I could use an SOD123 instead of an SMA?

Comment: Consider SOD123FL package with equivalent Electrical characteristics like you selected, forward voltage, capacitance, with current rating same or higher.